# Debian root partition greater than 2TB

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, debian, raid

I have two internal hard drives: a 4TB drive and a 750GB drive. After selecting RAID0 and installing Debian (wheezy) to a single partition, I ran `fdisk -l` which reported that the size of my root partition (/dev/sda1) was 1.4T. So, I've got a couple of questions....

1) I know that fdisk only allows up to 2TB so even if my (4TB + 750GB) drive was being restricted to 2TB, what happened to the other 0.6TB? Remember, I installed everything to one partition.

2) My ultimate goal is to have everything on a single 4TB partition. I've read about `parted` but everything I read relates to partitioning and mounting a non-bootable partition. This doesn't apply to me as I'm using a single partition which contains `/boot`. What are my options?

Comment: Could you clarify your question. 1. How are you using a raid 0 with two different sized drives? 2. Is your drive GPT or MBR,

Comment: What is your kernel version ?
With v0.90 raid superblock and kernel <3.1, you have severe limitations. see : https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats

Comment: @Kwaio: Kernel is 3.2.0-4-686-pae.

Comment: Is your OS 64bit ? Is it up to date ? specifically, HBA drivers...

Comment: @spuder: Why shouldn't I be able to use raid 0 with two different sized drives? It's raid 0 (not raid 1), so there's no mirroring. The disks can be any size. I'm sure it's MBR. Don't think GPT would give me this problem to begin with.

Comment: A Raid0 array is of the size of its smallest drive. That is how it works, blocs are split between all drives.

Comment: @spuder: I see. Well the SAS configuration utility on my Dell server gave me two options to set up the RAID array: mirroring and striping. I chose striping. I thought that would have given me maximum space but I guess I was wrong. You're correct. I've ended up with 2 * 750GB = 1.5TB worth of space.

Comment: You could check if your dell server's raid card has JOBD. That sounds like what you are trying to accomplish, however I would discourage raid or JOBD in this setup because loosing one drive looses both. Instead consider using the 750 for the OS, and the 2tb for your data.

Comment: I've checked every menu option during boot and I can't remember any reference to JOBD. I don't think I can do what you've suggested spuder as the configuration requires me to choose either mirroring or striping. I can't have a single hdd either.                      I think my best bet is to replace the smaller (750GB) drive with one of the same size as the bigger one (4TB). I'd then have to re-install the OS with /boot under a different partition and finally run parted to create a partition greater than 2TB.

Please suggest better alternatives if there are any.

Comment: In both cases, remember stripping isn't safe. Either schedule regular backups or avoid storing data you don't want to loose there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up what we came with in the comments, here is your problem :

You are doing **stripping** (alias RAID-0) over two drives :

- a 4 TB one
- a 750 GB one

The size used on every drive of a RAID0 array is equal to the size of its smallest drive. Thus your array wil be **2*750 GB = 1.5GB**.
Removing a bit of overhead and GiB/GB confusion, this came up with a 1.4TB array.

From there your only option is to **use your drives separatly** (which you seem to be unable to do using your SAS card) or **replace the small drive by a 4TB one**.

Anyway, remember Stripping is **unsafe** as any drive failure will result in the loss of data stored on both disks, because any block of data is split between both drives.

Comment: One more comment: Once these problems are dealt with, GPT is more-or-less required to make use of an over-2TiB disk. Thus, the MBR partitioning should be scrapped and `parted` or `gdisk` (not `fdisk`, except *very* recent versions) should be used to set the disk up with GPT. Also, I do not generally recommend using a single partition on such a big disk. At the very least, root (`/`) should be separated from user data (usually in `/home` for workstations; often in `/var` on servers), and a separate swap partition is often in order.

Comment: For some reason, swap turned out to be in a separate partition by default. The server is primarily used to backup another server and it is itself backed up on a regular basis. So there's no need for home directories and I am not worried about data loss. Thanks a lot for all the responses.